# Flow builder + quick action

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps, quickaction, flow-builder

I set up a flow builder + a quick action to update the lead status but it doesn't work.
My quick action button is there but nothing happen when I click on it.
Do you any advice to manage this?
Here my screen:
[image: flow]

[image: flow]

[image: flow]

[image: quick action]

Comment: Does the user have permission to run flows?

Comment: try to debug your flow by passing recordId. You will see if it is passing or giving any error.

Comment: why is your Update record element matching on ID field twice?